# Intellij Refactoring - Move inner object to own file

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, refactoring

I got this code fragment in a scala-file:

```
object types {
   object sTypes {
      sealed trait A
      case object B extends A
   }
}
```

I am looking for a way to extract the inner object sTypes into an own file. However if i use F6 on the inner object sTypes as suggested here: [Answer by Dmitry Jemerov](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206202739-Refactor-inner-class-to-its-own-class), it allways wants to extract the whole types object. Is there a quick way to soley extract the inner object?

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way is to move `sTypes` out of the `types` first. Collapse the object into a single line, cut it, and then paste it at the top level. You can then use F6 to move it to a new file.

Comment: This works, but i have to manually adjust all imports regarding `import types.sTypes`. I was hoping to get around that.